# Software for managing blog on Blogger

Tags: linux, text-editor, google-apps

I need an application for managing my blog on [Blogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_%28service%29).

Ideally the software should have the following features/characteristics:

1. Supports Blogger platform.
2. Text editor that supports Markdown and LaTeX if possible. Markdown preview is optional but highly appreciated.
3. The software should be able to work offline and lets you save offline drafts.
4. Drafts should be available to be sent by email or to be exported as a .txt or .md document format.
5. Available for Windows **and Linux**. (Linux only is fine too.)
6. Available for tablet (either iOS or Android is fine).